# case inside function

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getNumberOfPersons(num int)
RETURNS numeric LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
CASE WHEN (SELECT * FROM getTotalPersons(num)) is not null THEN SELECT getPerson(num)+getTotalPersons(num)*getPerson(num) ELSE SELECT getPerson(num) END;
$$;
```

Before I used CASE with the same code (and only first branch), everything worked fine but now with CASE I get an error 'syntax error at or near CASE'. I do not see where my mistake is.

Comment: I'm baffled.  You use `getTotalPersons` as both a scalar and a table reference.  This code doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `language sql` functions you can't have a [PL/pgSQL CASE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.6.7) only a [CASE expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

But neither is needed here. A simple coalesce will do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getNumberOfPersons(num int)
RETURNS numeric LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
  select coalesce(getTotalPersons(num),1) * getPerson(num);
$$;
```

---

Btw: a scalar function shouldn't be used like a table function. 
So, `SELECT * FROM getTotalPersons(num)` should be `select getTotalPersons(num)`